# npm install tulind in my crypto server side

Tags: cryptography, tradingview-api

iget this error when  install tulind by usin npm install tulind when install instedy of runing server I get this erro aing-bot\node_modules\tulind
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-buildinstall